# Getting javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Unable to resolve while connecting to database through weblogic datasource

Tags: jdbc, weblogic-10.x

I am trying to get datasource object from client program and the target machine for the datasource created in weblogic console is other machine..

please let me know whether my approach is correct or not

PFB code snippet...

```
    Connection conn1=null;

    javax.sql.DataSource ds=null;

    Hashtable ht=new Hashtable();

    Context initialContext=null;

    try {
        ht.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
        ht.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "t3://hostname:port/");
        ht.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "xxxxx");
        ht.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "xxxxx");

         initialContext=new InitialContext(ht);
        System.out.println("got initial context");

        ds=(javax.sql.DataSource)initialContext.lookup("SampleConnection1");
        try {
        conn1=ds.getConnection();

        Statement stmt = conn1.createStatement();
        ResultSet rset = stmt
        .executeQuery("select  1 from dual");
        if (rset.next())
        System.out.println(rset.getString(1));

        rset.close();
        stmt.close();
        conn1.close();


            conn1= ds.getConnection();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

getting below error...

javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Unable to resolve 'SampleConnection1'. Resolved '' [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Unable to resolve 'SampleConnection1'. Resolved '']; remaining name 'SampleConnection1'
    at weblogic.rjvm.ResponseImpl.unmarshalReturn(ResponseImpl.java:234)
    at weblogic.rmi.cluster.ClusterableRemoteRef.invoke(ClusterableRemoteRef.java:348)
    at weblogic.rmi.cluster.ClusterableRemoteRef.invoke(ClusterableRemoteRef.java:259)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.ServerNamingNode_1034_WLStub.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLContextImpl.lookup(WLContextImpl.java:423)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLContextImpl.lookup(WLContextImpl.java:411)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at ConnectToJNDI.getJndiConnection(ConnectToJNDI.java:45)
    at ConnectToJNDI.main(ConnectToJNDI.java:28)
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Unable to resolve 'SampleConnection1'. Resolved ''
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.newNameNotFoundException(BasicNamingNode.java:1139)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.lookupHere(BasicNamingNode.java:252)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.ServerNamingNode.lookupHere(ServerNamingNode.java:182)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.lookup(BasicNamingNode.java:206)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.RootNamingNode_WLSkel.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.invoke(BasicServerRef.java:667)
    at weblogic.rmi.cluster.ClusterableServerRef.invoke(ClusterableServerRef.java:230)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef$1.run(BasicServerRef.java:522)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:363)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:146)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.handleRequest(BasicServerRef.java:518)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.wls.WLSExecuteRequest.run(WLSExecuteRequest.java:118)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:207)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:176)

please suggest how to resolve this....

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your code matches the name of the data source exactly as configured in the console, I would make sure that you assigned a target server for the datasource.

Comment: used same name as configured in the console and assigned target to server for the datasource still getting same error

Comment: Do you see in the WebLogic startup logs where the datasource is being initialized? Any errors on startup?